# min n-m so that whole array will be sorted

Tags: java, algorithm

I was asked the below question in an interview:

```
Given an array of integers, write a method to find indices m and n such that 
if you sorted elements m through n, the entire array would be sorted. Minimize
n-m. i.e. find smallest sequence.
```

find my answer below and please do comment on the solution. Thanks!!!

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question! But please do keep them separated. I would suggest adding an answer with your answer to this question, and then editing the question to just be your question.

Comment: i could not understand your point. Sorry.

Comment: A question should be a question _only_. Please edit your question so that it contains only your question. Then, you can answer your own question normally using the `Your Answer` box.

Comment: @Telthien i have done!!!

Comment: Sweet! Interesting solution, by the way!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At last I have got a solution to the problem, please feel free to comment.

Lets take an example:

```
int a[] = {1,3,4,6,10,6,16,12,13,15,16,19,20,22,25}
```

Now if i will put this in to the graph (X-coordinate -> array index and Y-coordinate -> array's value) then the graph will look like as below:
[image]

Now if we see the graph there are two places where dip happens one is after 10 and another after 16. Now in the zig zag portion if we see the min value is 6 and max val is 16. So the portion which we should sort to make the whole array sorted is between (6,16). Please refer to the below image:

[image]

Now we can easily divide the array in to three part. And middle part the one which we want to sort so that the whole array will be sorted. Please provide your valuable inputs. I tried to explain to my label best, please let me know if i want to explain more. Waiting for valuable inputs.

The below code implements the above logic:

```
public void getMN(int[] a)
{
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE; int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for(int i=1; i<a.length; i++)
    {
        if(a[i]<a[i-1])
        {
            if(a[i-1] > max)
            {
                max = a[i-1];
            }
            if(a[i] < min)
            {
                min = a[i];
            }
        }
    }
    if(max == Integer.MIN_VALUE){System.out.println("Array already sorted!!!");}
    int m =-1, n =-1;
    for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++)
    {
        if(a[i]<=min)
        {
            m++;
        }
        else
        {
            m++;
            break;
        }
    }
    for(int i=a.length-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        if(a[i]>=max)
        {
            n++;
        }
        else
        {
            n++;
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(m +" : "+(a.length-1-n));
    System.out.println(min +" : "+max);
}
```

Comment: add comments, so that newcomers can understand it easily too.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I came up with something like that:

```
public static void sortMthroughN(int[] a)
{   
    int m = -1;
    int n = -1;
    int k = -1;
    int l = -1;
    int biggest;
    int smallest;
    // Loop through to find the start of the unsorted array.
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length-1; i++)
        if(a[i] > a[i+1]) {
            m = i;
            break;
        }
    // Loop back through to find the end of the unsorted array.
    for(int i = a.length-2; i > 0; i--)
        if(a[i] > a[i+1]) {
            n = i;
            break;
        }
    biggest = smallest = a[m];
    // Find the biggest and the smallest integers in the unsorted array.
    for(int i = m+1; i < n+1; i++) {
        if(a[i] < smallest)
            smallest = a[i];
        if(a[i] > biggest)
            biggest = a[i];
    }

    // Now, let's find the right places of the biggest and smallest integers. 
    for(int i = n; i < a.length-1; i++)
        if(a[i+1] >= biggest) {
            k = i+1;      //1
            break;
        }

    for(int i = m; i > 0; i--)
        if(a[i-1] <= smallest) {                               
            l = i-1;    //2
            break;
        }
            // After finding the right places of the biggest and the smallest integers
            // in the unsorted array, these indices is going to be the m and n.
    System.out.println("Start indice: " + l);
    System.out.println("End indice: " + k);

}
```

But, I see that results are not the same with your solution @Trying, did i misunderstand the question? By the way, at the and of your code, it prints

```
4 : 9
6 : 16
```

What are these? Which ones are indices?

Thanks.

EDIT: by adding place marked as 1 this:

```
            if(a[i+1] == biggest) {
                k = i;
                break;
            }
```

and 2:

```
        if(a[i+1] == smallest) {
            l = i;
            break;
         }
```

it is better.

Comment: 4 is the starting index from where the sorting will start which is the place of 10 and the last index is 9 i.e. the place of 15 currently. And 6 is minimum  num of the unsorted array and 16 is the maximum of the unsorted array. Hope it clarifies things!!

Comment: Fair enough.:) 3 is the start indice and 10 is the end. I think, I have a problem with equality. Nice solution by the way.;)

Comment: i am starting the array index from 0. As from my algo the min is 6 and max is 16, and as i have to minimize the n-m so i am neglecting 6 and 16 which are at 10 and 3 places respectively. Hence the sorting sub-part starts from 4 to 9 both included. Is it clear or am i missing something?

Comment: Are you in sync with my solution or disagreeing to it? As we all are learning simultaneously.

Comment: Your answer is correct. Before editing my code, I found the answer as 3, 10; because I didn't give any attention to equality part. Increasing the index if it is equal(or decreasing) is the correct way. I fixed the problem by adding that these two parts of code.

Comment: i think you should add this line `l = m, k = n;`

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to find the max value starting from the end of array:

```
public void FindMinSequenceToSort(int[] arr)
{
    if(arr == null || arr.length == 0) return;

    int m = 0, min = findMinVal(arr);
    int n = arr.length - 1, max = findMaxVal(arr);

    while(arr[m] < min)
    {
        m ++;
    }

    while(arr[n] > max)
    {
        n --;
    }

    System.out.println(m);
    System.out.println(n);
}

private int findMinVal(int[] arr)
{
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for(int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        if(arr[i] < arr[i-1] && arr[i] < min)
        {
            min = arr[i];
        }
    }

    return min;
}

private int findMaxVal(int[] arr)
{
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for(int i = arr.length - 2; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if(arr[i] >= arr[i+1] && arr[i] > max)
        {
            max = arr[i];
        }
    }

    return max;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can have two pointers and the last pointer moves backward to check start index of the shortest unsorted sequence. It's kind of O(N2) but it is more cleaner.

```
public static int[] findMinUnsortedSequence(int[] array) {
        int firstStartIndex = 0;
        int startIndex = 0;
        int endIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                if (array[j] <= array[i]) {
                    startIndex = j + 1;
                } else {
                    endIndex = i;
                    if (firstStartIndex == 0) {
                        firstStartIndex = startIndex;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return new int[]{firstStartIndex, endIndex};
    }
```